# Mapped drive in classic asp on IIS 7 Windows Server 2008 x64

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, asp-classic

I have classic asp app which I am trying to move from Win2000 Server to Windows Server 2008 x64. Everything seems to be working except file upload feature. It is implemented using 
FileSystemObject and for the storage server access it uses using mapped drive. 
I configured app pool to use domain user identity and created the mapping using NET USE under this same user identity. In the app pool settings "Load Profile" setting is true. Still the app does not see the the mapped drive. If I use UNC path directly in test page everything works fine. 
But to change it throughout the application would be unfeasible. 
Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

One solutions we did for a legacy app with a similar problem was to keep app pool identity always logged on as a user in a session.

Comment: I finished up mounting the share with vbscript in global.asa  Application_OnStart